# How to verify signed certificate?

Tags: ssl

I have two SSL certificates:

- One for `snipsalonsoftware.com` which is currently in place and working properly.
- One for `app.snipsalonsoftware.com` which has been purchased but not yet installed.

What I'm trying to do right now is simply verify the validity of the `snipsalonsoftware.com` certificate so that, when I try to verify the `app.snipsalonsoftware.com`, I know that I'm getting a meaningful answer.

This is a professionally signed certificate from Comodo by way of DreamHost, not a self-signed certificate. How can I verify the trust chain using `openssl` or some other method?

Here's what I get right now when I try:

```
$ openssl verify domain.pem 
domain.pem: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by New Dream Network, LLC/OU=DreamHost Basic SSL/CN=snipsalonsoftware.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But to me it's like duh, of course you can't get the local certificate - there isn't one. I don't get how I'm supposed to verify a professionally-signed certificate.

Answer (score 7):

Generally what this means is that OpenSSL's default CA path doesn't contain the certificate that signed the one you're checking - usually an intermediate certificate.

You'll need to get a copy of the intermediate (most CAs will provide, or you can fetch it from an SSL connection whose trust is working), and point at it in your `openssl` command with `-CAfile intermediate.pem`.

Comment: Note that if you use `-CAfile intermediate.pem` then you're telling openssl that the intermediate is fully trusted, which means you're not verifying the whole chain, just the last step. If this matters to you, you should use `cat intermediate.pem yourcert.pem | openssl verify` instead.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley `cat intermediate.pem garbage.pem | openssl verify` also says OK, seems that only verifies intermediate is signed by your trust roots, and nothing about yourcert :-(

Comment: To verify the intermediate.pem you should run `openssl verify intermediate.pem`. Without `-CApath` or `-CAfile` parameter you will verify it with your system root certs. (In case of a problem with those I recommend using https://certifi.io/en/latest/ )

Comment: Late but since this revived @WumpusQ.Wumbley: OpenSSL releases below 1.1.0 in 2016 _never_ accept a cert chain unless it reaches a locally-trusted _root_, so `-CAfile intermediate` is insufficient by itself but may help if the defaulted CApath contains its root (and any higher chain, less likely). 1.1.0 will accept a non-root as anchor only if you specify `-partial_chain`. The best solution is to provide the full chain in any combination of CAfile (usually more convenient) CApath (needs hashnames) and -untrusted but the root not in the last.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download from your provider all the certificates that form the [chain of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_path_validation_algorithm) from you signed certificate up to the signing Certificate Authority.

Then use `openssl verify` using those certs. Check both the `-CAfile` and the `-CApath` options of the `verify(1)` command to learn how.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an online tool like [SSL-Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) which graphically shows the trust chain your server is presenting and helps you to figure out which certificates are missing in the chain

Answer (score 0):

You have must ***cat*** all certs to final CA_Chain.crt:

```
:~$ cat RootCA.crt IntermediateCert1 IntermediateCert2 > CA_Chain.crt

:~$ openssl verify -CAfile CA_Chain.crt website.crt

(website.crt sign by IntermediateCert2)
```